# Anderson Darling Test on student-T distribution

Tags: t-distribution, anderson-darling-test

I would like to do an Anderson Darling test in R using ad.test() from the package “goftest”.
**My null hypothesis is H0:** Data follows a student-t distribution with 2 degrees of freedom.

I receive the statistic “An” and the “p-value”.

To decide (on a 5% level) whether to reject H0 or not, I could:

a)Compare “An” with a critical value.
**QUESTION:** But how do I know what this critical value is? 
R does not show a critical value. Is there a table where I can look it up or a formula from a paper.

Or

b)I could just look at the p-value. If I receive a p-value smaller than 0.05, I will reject H0. 
**QUESTION:** But how is the p-value calculated in my case? Is there a literature that shows a formula?

Note: The anderson darling test can test any distribution. But I didn't find literature that shows me how to do it when testing if the data comes from a student-T.

In case a reproducible example is needed for discussion, I propose:

```
library(goftest) 

set.seed(403)
data<-rt(n = 300, df=2)

ad.test(x = data,null = "pt", df = 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

For a fully specified distribution, the Anderson-Darling - as with the Kolmogorov-Smirnov, the Cramer-von Mises, the Kuiper test and many other ecdf-based tests - is distribution-free.

So you don't need tables for the 'standard t' such as that represented by the cdf function `pt`. All you need do is apply `pt` to your data (`data`$^\dagger$) and test *that* for uniformity ... which is effectively what these tests all do, and that's how `goftest::ad.test` works -- it uses fully specified distributions.

The asymptotic distribution of the Anderson-Darling test statistic for completely specified distributions was worked out by Anderson and Darling (1952, 1954) -- the 1952 paper gives the theory of computation of the asymptotic distribution (of a large class of tests of the Cramer-von Mises type, including specific discussion of what would become known as the Anderson-Darling test) and the 1954 paper gives asymptotic 10%, 5% and 1% critical values for the Anderson-Darling statistic.

In that paper they say that convergence to the asymptotic distribution is rapid and suggest it should be okay by $n=40$. Stephens (1974) suggests using it for $n\ge 5$.

Peter Lewis (1961) did tabulations of the distribution for $n\le 8$.

A little testing of `goftest::ad.test` suggests that the code *isn't* using the asymptotic distribution down at n=10, however (e.g. simulation at n=10 shows that the 5% CV there is around 2.512, which is larger than the asymptotic value). So if all else fails, let's read the help.

The help for `ad.test` refers to Marsaglia and Marsaglia (2004). They use simulation for $n=2^k$ for $k=3,4,5,6,7$ to identify a simple 3-piece transformation of the small-sample test statistic (scaled by 1/n) so that the asymptotic distribution can be used for small $n$. So it seems their code takes the statistic, scales it a little bit according to their piecewise transformation, and then compares that to the asymptotic distribution.

Anderson, T. W.; Darling, D. A. (1952).
"Asymptotic theory of certain "goodness-of-fit" criteria based on stochastic processes"
*Annals of Mathematical Statistics* **23**: 193–212.

Anderson, T.W. and Darling, D.A. (1954).
"A Test of Goodness-of-Fit",
*Journal of the American Statistical Association* **49**: 765–769.

Stephens M.A. (1974)
"EDF Statistics for Goodness of Fit and Some Comparisons,"
*Journal of the American Statistical Association*, **69**:347 730-737

P.A. Lewis, (1961),
"Distribution of the Anderson-Darling Statistic,"
Ann. Math. Stat., **32** 1118-1124.

Marsaglia, G. and Marsaglia, J. (2004)
"Evaluating the Anderson-Darling Distribution."
*Journal of Statistical Software*, **9** (2), 1-5.  February.
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v09/i02

$\dagger$ About which:

```
install.packages("fortunes")
library(fortunes)
fortune(77)
```

Answer (score 0):

For n > 5, the critical values for `An` when testing the data against a fully specified distribution are 1.933 at the 10% significance level and 2.492 at the 5% significance level. If your `An` is lower than this then your p-value will be significant and you would reject H0. Source: Table 1A from http://www.math.utah.edu/~morris/Courses/6010/p1/writeup/ks.pdf

This link also lists some references related to critical values, some of which have been picked up on by the previous answer from Glen_b